# Що значить скорочення "Б.П." на могилі?

Tags: значення-слів, скорочення

Що значить скорочення "Б.П." на цій могилі? Напис на могилі:

Б. П.

Анна Косоноцка

ур. 1894 ум. 1955

Мір праху твоєму

[image]

Comment: Похована в [Холмі](http://necropolis.uinp.gov.ua/burial?id=2656721275652670858). Перше, що спадає на думку: «Боже поможи» або радше «Боже помилуй». Але, зьвісно, треба доказова база для повної відповідї.

Comment: Я не міг підтвердити цю думку, але один сказав, же то «безьвісно пропавша».